# mysql query for long query to execute in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, java-stored-procedures

I got a hash map in java like this

```
{(1,'2018-06-29 10:19:33'),(4,'2018-06-29 10:19:34'),(10,'2018-06-29 10:19:38'),....}
```

The length of map could go as high as 3000

and a mysql table

```
id   name             updated
1,  firstProduct,    2018-06-29 09:19:33
2,  secondproduct,   2014-06-29 10:19:33
4,  fourthproduct,   2016-06-29 09:19:33
10, tenthproduct,   2018-06-29 06:13:32
.......
```

the key in the map is a id field in the table and the value is the updated timestamp field.

I would like to get all the products in the table whose timestamp is greater that value in the map.

like

```
select * from products where id = 1 and updated >  '2018-06-29 10:19:33'
select * from products where id = 4 and updated >  '2018-06-29 10:19:34'
...
```

But there could be as many as 3000 entries in the map.

I am thinking of passing the map values to mysql stored procedure. Inside the procedure a while loop will execute select statement for each map entry into a result set and finally return the result set back to java program.

Would like to know if this is possible and i feel there is a better solution for this but cant figure out.

Comment: Please finally learn to format your posts.

Comment: Why a stored procedure, what benefit do we hope to achieve by creating another object in the database? And I wouldn't do individual queries in while loop, I would use `UNION ALL` set operator to combine query results into single resultset. Why not just generate the required statement in Java?

Comment: The statement could get very huge as this could be for 3000 records and I though there is a character limit in sql query statement.

Comment: in MySQL, the size of a SQL statement is limited by `max_allowed_packet` system variable (on server, and on client) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet  Doing `UNION ALL` query at  90 characters per `UNION ALL SELECT`, that's 3000*90 = 270,000 characters, ~264 KB,  or ~ 0.25 MB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would dynamically generate a statement in Java.

Either:

```
 SELECT p.id, p.name, p.update 
   FROM products p
  WHERE 1=0 
     OR ( p.id = ? AND updated > ? )
     OR ( p.id = ? AND updated > ? )
     OR ( p.id = ? AND updated > ? )
```

(MySQL likely won't make effective use of an index for that query.)

Or, we could do :

```
 SELECT p.id, p.name, p.update FROM products p WHERE p.id = ? AND updated > ?
 UNION ALL
 SELECT p.id, p.name, p.update FROM products p WHERE p.id = ? AND updated > ?
 UNION ALL
 SELECT p.id, p.name, p.update FROM products p WHERE p.id = ? AND updated > ?
```

With an appropriate index defined, each SELECT could make effective use of that. But with this approach, we are probably going to hit an upper limit on the number of table references in a single query.  So this approach may need to be broken up into chunks.

---

Personally, I wouldn't hide the complexity in a database procedure.

It's not clear what benefit we would gain by implementing a database procedure.

Comment: "hide the complexity in a database procedure" I agree with this. The reason for storedprocedure was  my select statement has 2270 characters and I though there is a limit for character but found out mysql packet size is big enough to handle the query. Thanks.

Comment: The maximum size of a SQL statement is limited by `max_allowed_packet` system variable. Note that a SQL statement generated within a stored procedure is subject to the same limitation.  (A stored procedure isn't a really a workaround to the problem, unless we're creating a temporary table, then inserting rows to the temporary table in the loop, and then running a small SELECT statement to return the contents of the temporary table. But we could do that from client/application code just as easily as we could do it in a procedure.)